# Restating a part of the definition

Tags: theorems, thmtools, newtheorem, definition

I am repeating a single definition several times, and I use `restatable` to do so. But I want the first occurrence of a definition to contain a qualification which is not repeated in the next occurrences (e.g., I want ''(where this is a qualification)'' below to occur only the first time the definition is stated, but not when it's restated). What's the simplest way to achieve this result?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}


\begin{restatable}[Definition]{Definition}{Definition}
\label{def:definition}
 This is a definition
 (where this is a qualification.)

\end{restatable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of keywords you use reminds me of Major Major Major Major. ;-) Beware that the syntax is quite precise:

1. the optional argument is an attribution;
2. the first mandatory argument is the environment's name, in this case `definition`;
3. the second mandatory argument is a command name (without backslash) that will be used to restate the statement.

Here I (ab)use the way `thmtools` manages restatements: when absorbing the text and stating the theorem the first time, the conditional `\ifthmt@thisistheone` is set to true; in a restatement it is set to false.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\qualification}[1]{\ifthmt@thisistheone#1\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{restatable}[Test]{definition}{testdef}
\label{def:definition}
This is a definition\qualification{ (where this is a qualification)}.
\end{restatable}

\section{New}

\testdef*

\end{document}
```

[image]